# How to clear focus of multiple EditText fields in a ScrollView efficiently?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-scrollview

I have the following code:

```
public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

public void setupDialog(View view) {
    // Set up touch listener for non-text box views to hide keyboard.
    if (!(view instanceof EditText)) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                hideKeyboard(view);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    //If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion.
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
            setupDialog(innerView);
        }
    }
}

public void setupEditTextFocusChangedListeners(View view) {
    if (view instanceof EditText) {
        view.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    ((EditText) view).setSelection(((EditText) view).getText().length());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
            setupEditTextFocusChangedListeners(innerView);
        }
    }
}
```

While the keyboard hides as it should when clicking or scrolling outside of any of the EditText fields, when scrolling the EditText still retains focus even though the keyboard does dismiss.

The EditText fields are in a table format.  I know I could call `clearFocus()` on each EditText individually in `hideKeyboard`, but that doesn't seem like it would be efficient.  Is there a more efficient way to clear the focus of the EditText when scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As only one `EditText` can be focused and you have onFocused listener you can:

```
 private Edittext focused;
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                ((EditText) view).setSelection(((EditText) view).getText().length());
         focused =  view
  }
}
```

And then in hideKeyboard():

```
public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
focused.clearFocus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a horrible way of doing things.  You're going to screw up any touch listeners of any view other than the edit text, and its computationally expensive.  I'd really suggest you not do this as all-  this isn't iOS, you're expected to hit the back button to get rid of the keyboard.  Trying to make it work this way is more effort than its worth, and is difficult to get right.

Ignoring that-  a better way would be to make your root view of the scrollview focusable (and focusable in touch mode) with the focus of BEFORE_DESCENDENTS, and focus it onClick or onScroll.  Doing it that way means you don't need to set the onTouch of every view in the hierarchy, just the base.  Then in your root view onFocus, hide the keyboard when you gain focus.